# How do I remove the red rectangle when it collides with the cyan one?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    Random r = new Random();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int a = 5 * r.nextInt(150);
    int b = 5 * r.nextInt(90);

    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:/Users/Administrator/eclipse/My Projects/Game/src/bluebackground1.png");

    public Draw(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    //display
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, this);

        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fill3DRect(x, y, 50, 50, true);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw3DRect(a, b, 50, 50, true);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, 500, 800, 500);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Press R to restart the game", 10, 540);
        g.drawString("Use arrow keys to move", 600, 540);

        if(x == a && y == b){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 50));
            g.drawString("Victory", 300, 550);
        }
    }

    //controls
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            y -= 5;
        } else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            y += 5;
        } else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            x -= 5;
        } else if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            x += 5;
        }

        if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R){
            restart();
        }

        //border
        if(x < 0){
            x += 5;
        } else if(x > 745){
            x -= 5;
        } else if(y < 0){
            y += 5;
        } else if (y > 450){
            y -= 5;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {}

    //restart function
    public void restart(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        a = 5 * r.nextInt(150);
        b = 5 * r.nextInt(90);
    }
}
```

What I want is when the cyan rectangle which is moveable gets inside the red rectangle which is not moveable the red rectangle disappears permanently because the game is not over and the cyan rectangle will have to move more.

How do I remove the red rectangle when it collides with the cyan one?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1):

Store `Shape` instances in a `List`.  At time of painting, iterate the list and draw each one.  When one shape is removed, remove it from the list and call `repaint()`.

Comment: @mKorbel Oops!  Yes I meant a collection, as might be found in an `ArrayList` or `Vector` as opposed to a GUI component.  :P